# Java endsWith() not working as expected

Tags: java

I'm probably just overlooking something obvious, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this section of code is not working.

```
if(txtFileLocation.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".twn")){
            file = new File(txtFileLocation.getText());
        } else {
            file = new File(txtFileLocation.getText() + ".twn");
            System.out.println(txtFileLocation.getText() + " didn't end in .twn, so appending it");
        }
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
```

The output is as followers:

```
C:\temp\netprimaries1.twn didn't end in .twn, so appending it 
C:\temp\netprimaries1.twn.twn
```

Why doesn't endsWith(".twn") return true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you are calling `toString` and not `getText` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

`txtFileLocation.toString()` isn't `txtFileLocation.getText()`.

Answer (score 0):

`txtFileLocation.toString()` will probably return the object address in JVM, something like `TextField@0x232431`. You should use `txtFileLocation.getText()` to get the actual text held by the `TextField` control